I have this issue between AppSheets and Google Sheets, when I insert a new Google Sheet Lines with AppSheets
How can I solve the "arguments delimiters" in AppSheets to match Google Sheets formulas?
Google Sheet Formula:
=IF(Ingresos_y_Egresos[Fecha]="";"";
   IF(Ingresos_y_Egresos[Imputación]="Egreso";
     IF(Ingresos_y_Egresos[Divisa]=ARS;
       IF(Ingresos_y_Egresos[Importe Operación]="";"";
          Ingresos_y_Egresos[Importe Operación]*-1
         )
       ;
       ""
       )
     ;
     ""
     )
    )

AppSheets Formula: (inserted in Google Sheet)
=IF(Ingresos_y_Egresos[Fecha]="","",IF(Ingresos_y_Egresos[Imputación]="Egreso",IF(Ingresos_y_Egresos[Divisa]=ARS,IF(Ingresos_y_Egresos[Importe Operación]="","",Ingresos_y_Egresos[Importe Operación]*-1),""),""))

I checked the Google Sheets Locale and seems ok

Welcome to SO! Please clarify the issue, and try to write a more meaningful title. See How to ask.
